# Change element style before first render

Tags: javascript

For example I want to change  background depeding on some dynamic data(sync) and I want to apply this styling before page.html is rendered.
Is it possible?
If I use

```
<body>
 <script src="script.js" />
</body>
```

script.js

```
 let color = dynamicData();
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
```

It will (flicker) load default body color and then change it to the dynamicData

dynamicData is some information that we can get for example depending on time of day.

Comment: The server knows about that data upfront before serving the HTML?

Comment: It is not server side rendered.

Comment: ...is `dynamicData()` fetching some external resource, or what? Is the data inline available at load time? Can you please [edit] to add more info to the question?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan added more info. dynamicData is a synchronous function

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent your page has been rendered after user hits the url since you wanted to control this on the client side. But if you are also able to interact to server-side. You can try to add style attribute to your body tag before sending the page to user;

```
<body style="background-color:oldlace;">
```

But still the page will be look in white or empty until your request done. This is the reason that we are using the loaders/progress animations during the initial loads for web pages.